# Android Studio and Gradle, argument 0 for @NotNull parameter

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to make an app with Gradle in Android Studio, but all I get is this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/android/tools/idea/jps/builder/AndroidGradleBuilder.createBuildTask must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/android/tools/idea/jps/builder/AndroidGradleBuilder.createBuildTask must not be null
```

I've tried debugging this and I actually can't figure out what the problem is.

Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same error (while doing the same thing). I didn't found a way to get rid of it, but it seems to me that it only append after I installed the last AS build: Build #AI-130.700763

Comment: Maybe there is a bug, but if it was widespread and non-fixable it should be a bigger outcry, at least that's my guess. It's annoying to say the least.

Comment: same issue here, but I want to note that running "gradle assemble" from console works just fine!

Comment: Yep, it works for me too. Seems the problem lies with Android Studio.

Comment: how about gradle build?

Comment: This is a regression. Can you please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug ? Please specify as much detail as possible, like OS, Java version etc. It would be really great if could please attach a project that reproduces this issue. That would save us a lot of time :-)

Comment: One of the reasons for this to happen could be configuration to the project not done through the build.gradle file but through the "Project Settings" wizards. It is likely that the Android-Gradle facet was added manually. When Studio adds it, it attaches some information to the facet, and this is the information that is currently missing.

Comment: If that's the case how do we add the missing infromation?

Comment: I confirmed yesterday that this error only occurs when you check the "Use external build" in the compiler settings. Why is this?

Comment: I had this problem when I somehow ended up with and android and android-gradle facet on my parent module for the project. Removing them in Project Settings fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had and read some discussion on Google+ about this and I figured I still do a few things wrong since my project still does not compile with Gradle.

BUT, I've fixed this issue and from my understanding is that if you use Gradle you should not have to go into Module Dependencies, because it should be setup from the Gradle files.

So the first advice I can give you is to quit Android Studio and delete the .idea folder and all the .iml files in the project folder.

After this, open Android Studio and import the project, and remember to point to the build.gradle in the root directory (basically you have a build.gradle file for the project folder and then one build.gradle file for every module), basically mimic the structure that a new project has.

This will almost certainly fix this problem and also start the project from Gradle.

But you might encounter other errors along the way which could be a hazzle to debug.

But at the moment Android Studio gives really non-infomative error messages sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, remember that uninstalling an application does not remove the previous configuration files used by Android Studio and X-Window.

So before launching your updated AS, remove the following files:

```
~/.AndroidStudio*
~/.java/.userPrefs
```

Comment: This was a problem when AS was still in heavy alpha. I was using a Mac at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, and it appeared to be because android and android-gradle facets were somehow added to the parent module the project.

Removing these facets in Project Properties> Modules fixed the problem.