# Error when creating new project in android studio 3.3.2

Tags: android-studio, editor

When creating new project in android studio, the project can be created in the specified folder, But IDE throws the below error:

> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'file' of
>   com/intellij/vcsUtil/VcsUtil.getVcsFor must not be null

So I can't create or import any project.what is 
missing in com .... /vcsUtil/VcsUtil.getVcsFor ? I browsed for many days.

Issue with "@NotNull parameter **'file'** ". How can I solve the issue?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937645/android-studio-3-2-1-cannot-sync-project-with-gradle-files-argument-for-notn?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084527/android-studio-and-gradle-argument-0-for-notnull-parameter

Comment: this is not my issue. that's why i mentioned parameter 'file'.. You are telling for message or some other builder

Comment: @PriyaRajan you found the solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
Actually my company network system blocked the required URL. I got full access in IP. Then it was rectified. I can create a new project without fail.